# WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient.login does not return done promise

Tags: cordova, azure, winjs, azure-mobile-services

I'm building an Apache Cordova mobile app, using Azure Mobile Services for authentication to Google. To do this I am using the WinJS azure client as such:

```
var client = new WindowsAzure.MobileServiceClient("<myMobileService>", "<myKey>");


function logIntoGoogle() {
    client.login("google").done(function(results){
            //do something
        },
        function (error) {
        alert(error);
    });
}
```

The application hits logIntoGoogle, and after a successful sign in, the app navigates to **[myMobileService]/login/done**, instead of returning the done promise, and executing the callback.

Am I missing something, please?

Answer (score 2):

OK so it turns out that the problem didn't lie with my usage of the azure API. It was more a setup/ configuration issue with my cordova app.

I needed to install the phonegap Device plugin 
(https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-device.git)

and the phonegap InAppBrowser plugin (https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git).

Once installed, the promise returned and the callback executed.

Comment: Please see the update I wrote to my answer which describes the somewhat cleaner way to try to fix the original problem without the need to install those plugins. Adding those plugins isn't actually the solution to your problem, rather a way around.

Comment: If you use the plugin we recently added on cordova.io (http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/com.microsoft.azure-mobile-services) The dependency (inAppBrowser) is specified there and install for you automatically.

I don't believe device should be required to make auth work.

Answer (score 0):

About what I originally told you about there not being promises on source code: I was wrong. After spending last few hours crawling through all the documentation about Microsoft Azure that is available, I finally seem to have even some kind of knowledge about what is actually going on.

There seems to be condition that the callback URL is be provided for authentication if the *isSingleSignOn* is not set to *true*. So you should try

```
client.login("google", null, true).done(function(results){
```

and so on to make it work.

I hope this solves your problem instead of my first answer. Please let me know if you still face problems with it, so I can dive even deeper on the code base.. :)

**Update**

Actually, it was exactly because of the fact you were running on Cordova without InAppBrowser. As I browsed through the code, I found out that there are **[3 login UIs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/tree/master/sdk/Javascript/src/LoginUis)** from which the used one is decided based on availability of them. From these three, the only one causing the URL redirect was the *WebAuthBroker* which is available only on Windows Phones. WebAuthBroker uses the  *Windows.Security.Authentication.Web.WebAuthenticationBroker* which again uses *authenticateAndContinue* which in case of not using *isSingleSignOn* causes the redirecting. This again leads to the solution I offered.

The other two UIs are for *Cordova popup* and *Browser popup*. This way it uses the "best" UI it thinks is available.

Comment: Thanks again for this @sanfor. I resolved this (will add as answer) but the problem wasn't actually with the azure code (or my use of it). I tried the code in a normal web browser and it worked fine. It just wasn't working in my cordova app. Turns out I needed to install the Device plugin and InAppBrowser plugin into my solution, and then it worked... Thanks very much again for time in looking into this!